# Can i replace ViewState with hidden fields?

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate, hidden-field

Can i replace ViewState with hidden fields?

```
ViewState["temp"] = "1";

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfield" runat="server" />
```

with `EnableViewState="false"`.

hdnfield value is stored at client?
Is this is a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're needing the field for. Upon initial render, it will appear like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnfield" id="hdnfield" value="Initial Value" />
```

If that's all you're after, you're in luck. If you change the value of hdnfield and your page does a postback, the value will be reset.

Comment: hdnfield.Value will stored in code file depends on the user(vary with different user). is there any issue with data switch over between users?

Comment: no. Just set the value for the specific user in the code behind.